# How many subsets are possible on circle?

Tags: combinatorics

We have elements on circle $A = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ are written in ascending order. Find number of subsets consist of $k$ elements, where every two elements are not neighbours on circle where $ 1 \leq  k \leq [\frac{n}{2}]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N_1$ be the number of integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+\dots  +x_k=n-k$$
with $x_i\geq 1$ for $i=1,\dots,k$. By using [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique, we get that
$$N_1=\binom{(n-k)-k+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}.$$
Note that $N_1$ is number of subsets which consist of $k$ elements AND CONTAIN $1$, where every two elements are not neighbours on circle (consider $x_i$ to be the number of elements between the $i$th element of the subset and $(i+1)$th element).

It remains to evaluate $N_0$, that is the number of subsets which DO NOT CONTAIN $1$. This is the number of integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+\dots  +x_{k+1}=n-1-k$$
with $x_i\geq 1$ for $i=2,\dots,k$ and $x_1,x_{k+1}\geq 0$. Hence
$$N_0=\binom{(n-1-k)-(k-1)+k}{k}=\binom{n-k}{k}.$$
Hence the total number of subsets is
$$N_1+N_0=\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-k}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-k-1}{ k-1}.$$

P.S. See [OEIS's A034807](https://oeis.org/A034807): the number of necklaces of $k$ black and $n - k$ white beads with no adjacent black beads.

Comment: Why sum of differences is equals to $n-k$ ?

Comment: What is $x_k$ ??? we have got only $k$ elements in subset

Comment: $x_k$ is the number of elements between $k$th element of the subset and the FIRST one (we are on circle).

Comment: May be you can help with other one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434965/find-the-number-of-n-husbands-placing